# mysql php : how to efficiently fetch previous X dates that include entries

Tags: php, mysql, date

Imagine a basic website where users post something on random dates. The system uses mysql-php and stores each post in a table, call tablePost, with a column storing the date (or time). Note that the user can post multiple posts in a day. What I want to achieve is to be able to fetch date of last 4 days (or even more) that user posted. Also the post information (postid, posttext etc) is to be fetched. An example output is:
- 2012-04-25 (3 posts, postinfo...)
- 2012-04-12 (2 posts, postinfo...)
- 2011-09-12 (33 posts, postinfo...)
- 2011-03-04 (10 posts, postinfo...)

I can imagine two solutions:

1) Use only tablePost table, iterate over entries by php and fetch required data

2) Create another table, call tableActiveDays. when a user posts, an entry (userId, dateDay) is inserted possibly with INSERT IGNORE or checking whether it has not been inserted before. Therefore, each (userId, dateDay) is unique. In this way, if I want to fetch last 4 active days, I can use a simple select ... order by ... limit by 4 query.

My questions are:
- Any other way to achieve this task ?
- What is the most efficient way to achieve this ?

Comment: 2 questions: (1) [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far; (2) what kind of `postinfo` you expect for cases when there 2, 3 or more posts per day?

Comment: (1): I have tried that I can implement both of the solutions I provided and functionally, they both work. I'm just starting a new project and I expect to have increasing traffic by the time. Therefore, I want to pick the optimal solution from the beginning.

(2) postinfo is expected to be around a few 200-300 character text columns.

Comment: So, please, show your working solution and describe why it is not suitable. What information you expect to find inside `postinfo` and in which format?

Comment: Indeed, my question is which approach is more suitable. I'm not expert  at efficient implementation/design of DBs. Intuitively I can say that, solution1 has the advantage of smaller storage requirement but deriving the information by php can be CPU intensive. solution2 requires extra table/storage but less work on php side. But I'm not sure which one is a better trade-off. Morever, there can be other solutions which are much more efficient than these.

Answer (score 0):

Create `INTEGER` field and call it "dt_timestamp". When user post message save in "dt_timestamp" result of `time()` function.

UPDATE: 
If you have registered users then add field with `INTEGER`type, call it `last_activity`. When user post something update this field with `time()`. Then use this query:

`SELECT pt.* FROM post_table pt JOIN users_table ut ON ut.id = pt.user_id WHERE` `pt.dt_timestamp >= ut.last_activity - 86400 * 4 AND ut.id = %needed_user_id%;`

`users_table` has field `id` - user's id. `post_table` has field `user_id` - field value from users_table.

Using `DATETIME` is much slower then just integer timestamp.

Comment: This solution looks at only 4 days back from today. But the 4 days that user posted are not necessarily 4 days from today. What I want to fetch is the 4 days that the user actually posted something.

Comment: then add to query " AND user_id = %id%"

Comment: It is not the issue. Imagine as an example that the user posted some staff during 2011 but did not post anything in 2012. According to your solution, the query will result no results. However, I want it to output the last 4 days the user posted during 2011.